# Make animate.css effects work onhover and onclick with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the `CSS3` animations from Dan Eden.

I'm having troubles to work with `jquery` for hover or click events.

Here's [the fiddle I'm working on](http://jsfiddle.net/TFfGL/115/).

1. Notice the div falls off the screen with the animated hinge effect, but then it comes back to where it was. I would need to it fall off the screen permanently, or until one reloads the page.
2. The `jquery` snippet you see in there is just an alternative fallback I've been using since I can't get `jquery` to work with `CSS` animations yet. (The snippet works on my site, but for some reason it doesn't work in the fiddle.)

So how do I fire off the `CSS` animations using `jquery` click (or hover) events?

Once clicked, the div shouldn't reappear.

Things I've tried:

`jquery addClass`, as per [Dan's suggestion](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md):

Example given on the above page URL:

```
$('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
```

I've also tried changing the `CSS3 .animated` and `.hinge` to use `:active`, but no luck, and if I recall correctly, it was still putting the div back instead of letting it fall away permanently.

If someone could point me in a direction. I spend days trying to make the whole thing work. I've mostly been reading everything I can find on this subjects; I want to LEARN how to do this, and not just have it fixed for me.

If there's any info I'm missing, I'm new to this forums so please go easy on me. :)

SOLUTION, SOLVED:

```
$('#pricetag_overlay1 a').click(function(){ 
            $('#pricetag_overlay1').toggleClass("animated hinge",function(){
               $(this).remove();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Your post was good, but you'd have to remember being more tidy when writing question. SO people want to quickly see the problem and what you are asking for. It must be very clear and clean. So try avoiding too many details about how long you have been working on this or useless comments. Also, it is a good thing to post your code directly in the question, because if the link break, we will have a hard time figuring out what was the initial issue. Moreover, you don't need to say hello, goodbye or stuff like that, your question is implicitly polite if you take time to write it.

Comment: Oh, and you could also have a look to the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq it's a good start point. By the way, I did appreciate the effort put in your question, it's not every newcomers that does it that way :)

Comment: OK I finally solved it (I'll edit my original post and insert solution)

Comment: Then you should answer your own question to allow other people that find your thread to have a solution. After 48 hours, you will be able to set your own answer as accepted!

Comment: You must really post it as an answer, because if you don't do that your answer will appear as not solved. Which won't be the case. So, just copy paste your Edit in an Answer. It's the proper way to do things on SO. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFfGL/117/) to work as you preferred

For monitoring CSS3 animation using jquery see [this link](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/how-to-control-css3-animations-and-css3-transitions-using-jquery/).

Note:

```
$(window).load(function(){})
```

the above script will only fire on the initial page load

so prefer using

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Comment: Thanks for beefing up the solution to include those 'transition end' parts; much obliged.